# Using multiple IP addresses on a VM instance on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, ip, virtual-machine, http-proxy

Good morning,
I am currently in the process of trying to set up a proxy network. I have rented an IP subnet and added this to Google Cloud and can now use these IP addresses to reach VM instances.

Now the problem is that I don't want to create a separate VM for each proxy to keep the costs as low as possible. So I am trying to add multiple IP addresses to a VM.
I have currently found two, more or less working, solutions:

1. forwarding rules https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts
   -> This works without problems. However, it makes no sense for me to bear the high costs for it. These costs are over $1800/m https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing for 256 proxies.
2. multiple network interfaces https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces
   -> Unfortunately you can only add 2 network interfaces with multiple VPC networks at the smallest instance size. So for 256 proxies you still need 128 VMs, which would cost high.

So I need a cheap way to forward as many IP addresses as possible to as few VM instances as possible. To be able to create a proxy network as cheap as possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can't do the same thing with a forwarding rules and a VM with multiple network interface. Do you really need 256 forwarding rules, in the same project? it sounds very weird. In addition of a default quota of 15 VPC network per project.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for your reply. As described above, I want to build a proxy network for normal webscraping and I am looking for a cheaper alternative than renting proxies from proxy companies. The forwarding rules or the multiple network interfaces were just some things I found when trying to use multiple IPs to reach my VM.

Comment: What is the purpose of 256 addresses? Are you trying to bypass security and access controls? Eidt your post and clarify what you are trying to accomplish so that the best answer can be created. Based on the details provided, the options you mentioned are your solution.